# Create Custom Maps Xcode?

Tags: ios, xcode, maps, mkmapview

I would like to Create a Custom Map !

There is a way to do it so as to add this map to Xcode ?

I have an example in this picture below:

http://a1.mzstatic.com/eu/r30/Purple2/v4/92/d6/a8/92d6a818-1966-3a87-da0e-1aa6251d7e6a/screen568x568.jpeg

Thanks

Comment: I don't think you mean to create a Custom Map, do you ? I guess what you are looking for is a map overlay. What are the thinks you want to customize in you map ? Please explain more what you are actually searching for ?

Comment: @BishalGhimire I'm searching to Create an Aviation map as this picture attached http://peter2000.co.uk/aviation/operational/map-jepp.jpg...! it means i've to be able to Put Annotations with the different airports thanks to a database.

Answer (score 1):

Many way to do it.
Easy one is add UIImageView to UIScrollView and enable zoom on scrollview.
this way you can have basic map not good in memory.

Or, you can use some opensource like Mapbox, you can custom tile image map.
https://www.mapbox.com/

Comment: Do you have some tutorial that introduce the creation of the map with map box ?

Comment: They have example in github you can try: https://github.com/mapbox/mapbox-ios-sdk

Comment: Unfortunately It doesn't help me ! :(